# Where can I find an updated asus-wmi-dkms package for Asus N56V?

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, asus, backlight, dkms

I'm trying to use the answer for 166261 question.
The suggested package ( install asus-wmi-dkms_0.2_all.deb.gz package (from http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12057336&postcount=49) ) seems not working for me.
There is any new package / ppa for asus-wmi-dkms ?

Description of my framework:

===========================================================

Machine: Asus N56V laptop

===========================================================

Software

- Kubuntu 12.04 amd64
- kernel linux-image-generic-lts-quantal (3.5.0.9-generic) and drivers from ubuntu-x-swat ppa

===========================================================

Hardware and problems

- after installation do not boot - SOLVED using boot-repair
- every couple of hours the system freezes - SOLVED using 3.5 kernel
- keybord FN keys - PARTIALLY WORKING (using asus-wmi -v 999.01)
- Keyboard backlight - NOT WORKING
- Nvidia GEFORCE GT - NOT USED glxgears says 60 fps
- Ethernet Atheros card - SOLVED install alx driver
- external subwoofer - SOLVED adding options snd-hda-intel model=asus-mode4

==========================================================

Solutions

see the asnwers to the 162047 and 166261 questions

==========================================================

Comment: Since you are using an unsupported, unofficial kernel, this is not surprising. Does the package work/build on the *official* 3.2.0-27 kernel?

Comment: well, as stated in the link, the .deb package was intended for the 3.5.0-2-generic kernel. The standard 12.04 kernel creates a lot of problems: all the hardware problems reported above (see the answer to 166261 question). The problem is that I cannot find any asus_wmi package (the only ppa I found is the Keng-Yu lin but it is for oneiric). So my question: is this module included in the kernel? Or it is mantained elsewere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest Quantal update brings kernel 3.5.0-11 which supports all (except brightness) functionbuttons out of the box. Be sure to remove the dkms module first!

Comment: I'll try asap. Now I have kernel 3.5.0-13-generic from ubuntu-x-swat/q-lts-backport/

Comment: Users expiriencing crashes and unbootable systems should have a look at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1041883

Comment: Hi, I've removed the dkms module with "sudo dkms remove --all -m asus-wmi -v 999.01". Then rebooted. All works well, but the FN key for brightness (as you said) and for keyboard backlight didin't work

Comment: You could always file a bugreport for that against the linux-kernel 
(https://bugzilla.kernel.org/) and it might just get fixed

Comment: Thanks. I'll file a bug this evening when I'll have access to the asus notebook

Comment: Filed as Bug 46791

Answer (score 3):

> 0) install quantal kernel headers
>   1) `tar zxvf asus-wmi.tar.gz` to `/usr/src/`
>   2) `sudo dkms build -m asus-wmi -v 999.01`
>   3) `sudo dkms install -m asus-wmi -v 999.01`

**Source:** http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12086401&postcount=27

Comment: Done, getting the kernel from ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/q-lts-backport - now the volume fn keys work correctly; but still no keyboard_backligth. A new directory appeared /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/leds/asus::kbd_backlight I'm investigating on the content

Comment: Investigating I've seen that /sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight/brightness contains the value 3 - This should indicate that the keyboerd_mackligth is on at the maximum brightness - Still it is not illuminted